# Use of URI method in mechanize#link

Tags: ruby, mechanize, mechanize-ruby

I am trying to get an URL from an available a tag. So If my html contains

```
<a class= "classname" href="someurl.com"; title="title">some text</a>
```

If I do something like this

```
@url = link.search("a[@href]")
```

It returns me the above html.

If I do `.text` then it returns me `Some text`.

But I want to get the `href url`. I have seen [this link](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/Mechanize/Page/Link.html#method-i-uri). but not getting how to implement it.

Any suggestions .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think mechanize uses [nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) to parse content. So, to get attribute's value you could use `attr` method and then get it's value, something like this:

```
link.search("a[@href]").attr('href').value
```

Comment: Actually, it should probably be: `link.at('a[href]')[:href]`